# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in BuildVersionIncrement

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After update Visual studio 2010 to VS2010 SP 1 I've got build error (but solution compiled successful)

```
Error   1   Could not check if project were modified because: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

and

```
 Error  2   System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
       at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
       at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)
       at BuildVersionIncrement.BuildVersionIncrementor.CheckProjectItem(ProjectItem item, DateTime outputFileDate)
       at BuildVersionIncrement.BuildVersionIncrementor.IsProjectModified(Project project)
       at BuildVersionIncrement.BuildVersionIncrementor.IsSolutionItemModified(SolutionItem solutionItem)
       at BuildVersionIncrement.BuildVersionIncrementor.UpdateRecursive(SolutionItem solutionItem)
```

My OS is WinXP SP3.
Regional settings is `Russian`,system date format is `dd.MM.yyyy`

AssemblyInfo.cs of project has autoincrement attribute

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Comment: When you use a "build version incrementor" then you are not supposed to use an autoincrement attribute.  Start at AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0") and let the "incrementor" do its job.  Or don't use it at all.

Comment: @Hans Passant 1st - its work before update.
2nd - I don't use any custom "incrementors". May be I don't understand how work Incrementors. I set `1.0.* ` to increment version after each build. Please,correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The stack trace clearly shows that you are in fact using a custom incrementor.  You'll have to get rid of it if you don't want to use it.  Whatever it takes, we don't know.  Maybe an add-in.

Comment: You're right. I disabled `Build Version Increment` and don't get build error.